# Erro ao executar login() 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: postgresql, django, login, forms-authentication

Estou tentando logar em uma conta do **django** para poder redirecionar para a pagina principal do meu projeto, mas o comando `login` me retorna o seguinte erro.

```
AttributeError at /login/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Estou usando OneToOneField para usar cnpj/senha de uma table no meu banco de dados.

Estou testando tanto com o login e senha do django quanto os da tabela e ambos devolvem o mesmo erro.

**views.py**

```
def login_log(request):
    form = PessoaForm(request.POST, None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cnpj = form.data['cnpj']
        senha = form.data['senha']
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(request, cnpj=cnpj, senha=senha)
            user2 = authenticate(request, username=cnpj, password=senha)
            print(user)
            print(user2)
            print(login(request, user))
            #return redirect('dashboard', idpessoa)
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

`idpessoa` é usado pra mandar junto da url e acessar o usuário que esta logando. No meu código ele tem a utilidade corretamente e está funcionando. (Apenas para desencargo de consciência que ele não é o erro)

Sei que o erro está nesta linha

```
print(login(request, user))
```

e o `print` está ali apenas para **testes**

> Caso necessario meu **forms.py**
>
> ```
> class PessoaForm(ModelForm):
>     class Meta:
>         model = User
>         fields = ['cnpj', 'senha']
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá

Tente retirar a `request` , isso pode ser o possivel erro.

```
user = authenticate(cnpj=cnpj, senha=senha)
```

E para redirecionar para umna outra pagina em caso de sucesso

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Vou dar um Exemplo que uso no meu sistema muito bom no `forms.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Pegque o dados necessarios do HTML
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        # Use a autenficação do Django
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        # Se tem usuario
        if user:
            #Checa se usuario esta ativo, é necessario para o futuro, caso voce destive o usuario ele não ira mais logar
            if user.is_active:
                # Logando.
                login(request,user)
                # SE LOGAR,Redireciona o usuario para uma pagina , nesse caso a Index .
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                # Envia para uma pagina dizendo:
                return HttpResponse("Sua conta não esta ativa.")
        else:
                #testes
                # print("Erro no login")
                # print("email usado: {} e senha {}".format(email,password))
                #essa parte é legal , mostra para o usuario uma resposta
                messages.error(request, 'Erro no email ou senha')
#volta para pagina do login para uma nova tentativa
            return redirect('login')

        else:
            #Inicianiliza a pagina.
            return render(request, '...login.html', {})
```

Use no `login.html` para aparecer o `messages.error` (eu uso `bootstrap`):

```
{% if messages %}                
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">                    
                      {% for message in messages %}
                           <div{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</div>
                      {% endfor %}
                </div>
             {% endif %}
```

Abraço,
E que a força esteja com você.

Comment: Obrigado novamente por descrever uma resposta completa e instrutiva! Não consigo mais testar pois não sei se consigo e se quero voltar naquele erro, mas acredito que se eu reproduzir seu código ira funcionar, e se não, ainda tem o outro post onde os outros erros são corrigidos.